# My python code freezes once it gets to "await ctx.wait_for_message(author=author, timeout=20)" for my discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to debug this for ages now and it could just be something really obvious that I just haven't seen but does anyone know what is going on here. I am trying to create a discord bot that can play blackjack and I am trying to ask the user a question in the server, read it and respond. everything else works perfectly fine on the bot but it is just this one part, here is the code for this specific part, I do not get any error it just reaches that line and then doesn't do anything but I can still call other commands. Thanks in advance:)

````
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def blackjack(ctx, bet):
    sender = (str(ctx.message.author.name))
    author = ctx.message.author
    rwallet = open(sender + ".txt", "r")
    wallet = rwallet.read()
    global dealer_cards
    dealer_cards = []
    global player_cards
    player_cards = []
    
    # Deal the cards
    # Display the cards
    # Dealer Cards
    # Player Cards
    while len(dealer_cards) != 2:
        dealer_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
        player_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
        if len(dealer_cards) == 2:
            if len(player_cards) == 2:
                print("test")
                await ctx.send("Dealer has ? & " +  str(dealer_cards[1]) + " You have " + str(player_cards))
                # Sum of the Dealer cards
                if sum(dealer_cards) == 21:
                        await ctx.send("Dealer has 21 and wins!")
                elif sum(dealer_cards) > 21:
                        await ctx.send("Dealer has busted!")
                    # Sum of the Player cards
                while sum(player_cards) < 21:
                    print("test")
                    await ctx.send(str("Do you want to stay or hit? "))
                    print("test")
                    response = await ctx.wait_for_message(author=author, timeout=20,)
                    if response.content.lower() == "hit":
                        player_cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
                        print("test")
                        await ctx.send("You now have a total of " + str(sum(player_cards)) + " from these cards ", player_cards)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no wait_for_message function in a context object.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#waiting-for-events

> Prior to v1.0, the machinery for waiting for an event outside of the event itself was done through two different functions, Client.wait_for_message and Client.wait_for_reaction. One problem with one such approach is that it did not allow you to wait for events outside of the ones provided by the library.

> In v1.0 the concept of waiting for another event has been generalised to work with any event as Client.wait_for().

You could have fairly easily solved this problem by using a debugger and running

```
dir(ctx)
```

I also recommend using their discord server, they have the ability to search the documentation using a bot.